# Qt connect QAction to function with arguments

Tags: c++, qt, qaction

In my Qt 5.6 program I need to connect `QMenu` Click (`QAction`) to function and provide some arguments. I can connect to function without arguments and it is working:

```
connect(MyAction, &QAction::triggered, function);
```

But, when I'm trying to add some arguments:

```
connect(MyAction, &QAction::triggered, function(arguments));
```

I'm getting an error:

> C2664: "QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject
>   *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const": can't convery arg 2 from "void (__thiscall QAction::* )(bool)"
>   to "const char *"

My example function:

```
void fuction(char x, char y, int z);
```

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`function(arguments)` is a function call, you want to bind the function to the arguments and create new callable object instead, using [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
connect(MyAction, &QAction::triggered, std::bind(function, arguments));
```

or you can use a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
connect(MyAction, &QAction::triggered, [this]()
{
    function(arguments);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `std::bind` as in:

```
connect(MyAction, &QAction::triggered, std::bind(&function, x, y, z));
```